# read php array having string and object in sub array

Tags: php

I have the following output sing var_dump.. How do I read the value of 'transferfrom' for each array ? The 'ST00576' and 'OT01606' are dynamic values.It can change on the subsequence arrays.

```
string(19) "TB3360    7D  B  70"
array(2) {
  ["ST00576"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (13) {
    ["transferfrom"]=>
    int(102)
    ["transferto"]=>
    int(66)
    ["BR_ID"]=>
    int(102)

  }
  ["OT01606"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (13) {
    ["transferfrom"]=>
    int(102)
    ["transferto"]=>
    int(66)
    ["BR_ID"]=>
    int(66)

  }
}

string(19) "TB3360    BL  A  75"
array(2) {
  ["ST00576"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (13) {
    ["transferfrom"]=>
    int(102)
    ["transferto"]=>
    int(66)
    ["BR_ID"]=>
    int(102)

  }
  ["OT01606"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (13) {
    ["transferfrom"]=>
    int(102)
    ["transferto"]=>
    int(66)
    ["BR_ID"]=>
    int(66)

  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but don't you just need a foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you need, but this will pick the `'transferfrom'` item out of each array entry and return an array with the same keys but strings as values.

```
$arr = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->transferfrom;
}, $arr);
```

Or:

```
function pick_transferfrom($item)
{
    return $item->transferfrom;
}

$arr = array_map('pick_transferfrom', $arr);
```

Result (shortened):

```
['OT01606' => 102, 'ST00576' => 102];
```

Or you can just iterate:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    $transferfrom = $item->transferfrom;
    // do whatever you like with $transferfrom and $key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arrays as $arr){
  $transferfrom = $arr['transferfrom'];
  //here you do whatever you want with $arr
  //...
}
```